# VS 2015 + universal app + mvvmcross 3.5.0 + sqlite

Tags: mvvmcross

I started a new universal app using vs 2015 ctp 5, mvvmcross 3.5.0 + sqllite plugin 3.5.0.

I am using the famous N=.... serie of vídeos, especificaly n=12 Collect A Bull as a reference.

I created a new pcl Project as a core and a universal app Project(3 projects), added nuget packages to core , wp8.1 and to w8.1, everything good so far.

Then i copied the service folder from N=12 sample, added related nuget packages.

My trouble is: at this line   _connection = factory.Create("collect.sql"); on repository i've got a exception :

A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsCommon.DLL

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The message is pretty clear cannot found sqlite3.dll i've seen some articles to add file and reference manually, but i did not see nothing on the vídeo, and the N-12 sample runs ok?

How the sample can access the mentioned sqlite dll, it could be related to universal app?

By comparison i found a missing reference in wp project: Community.CsharpSqlite.WP7 i added manually but does not solve.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to solve this i just have to download from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and add reference manually

Thanks to mohibsheth on jabbr room

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Sqlite -Version 3.2.1
```

from package manager console. It worked for me.
If directly it didn't worked, then remove all the packages and add all packages of version 3.2.2 like :

```
Install-Package MvvmCross -Version 3.2.2
Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.FieldBinding -Version 3.2.2
Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Messenger -Version 3.2.2
```

Still having problem with the packages?Uncheck Silverlight from Core project properties.

Version 3.5.0 raising problems for me too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i remove all nuget packages from core and win phone project then added 3.2.2 versions, and 3.2.1 to sqlite plugin. Same results. By the way the silverlight is unchecked from pcl core.

Comment: is N=12 running ok if you update to 3.5? It's also not a XAML WP app, which could be another difference

Comment: N=12 actually runs with 3.5 versions, so i added a wp 8.1 Project to N=12 and the exception happened again.Should be anything related with universal apps and profile of core to support it, i am kind of stuck here

Comment: I also try to move the core to a Universal Portable Project, same results, its drive me crazy i already spend a week now in this messy....

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [SQLite.Net-PCL project](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL).  I've heard of some success in people using that although I have not personally used it yet.

I just submitted a pull request to the [MvvmCross Community SQLite](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite) project to update it to MvvmCross 3.5 and unified iOS API - so you could give that a try as well.  There is no new NuGet for that yet however.  You'll need to clone the project and compile it yourself.